# In scientific writing is: Energy expended/ cost /consumed?

Tags: word-choice, register, tech-writing

In scientific writing, should I write **energy** is ***expended, cost*** or ***consumed***?

Which term is preferable? As in the example,

> Energy is expended/cost/consumed through deformation/vibration/friction.

Comment: Scientific and technical writing uses passive voice for method clarity and to avoid inappropriate anthropomorphism, but I don’t think it’s a general rule that passive voice has to be used throughout scientific works.

Comment: @OldPro "cost" in your sentence is a noun, not passive voice.

Comment: I think that it would be helpful if you were to edit your question. It certainly isn't clear to me what you are asking, in large part because the first sentence, at the end of which you have a question mark, is not a question but a statement, and the statment is not well formed. Do you mean something like, "In scientific writing when refering to energy, should I say that it is expended, or should I say that it is consumed?" ... but I am only guessing about exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

energy is said to be expended in English scientific texts as in these sentences:

1) Work Work is done when a force F is exerted to move an object over a distance d W = F × d unit of measure: the joule (J), 1 J = 1 N·m

> Energy is expended when a force acts over some distance to move an
>   object.  Not all forces do work.

[energy is expended](https://slideplayer.com/slide/9878245/)

2) How much energy is expended in this reaction?

[energy is expended, scientific publication](https://books.google.com/books?id=u0gmQ07nyyMC&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=science%20%2B%20physics%20%2B%20%22energy%20is%20expended%22&source=bl&ots=DOZ8GdmK-F&sig=ACfU3U1m2z5PET_HUc5PaDnST7v6TgexDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0xc7VlozgAhXxV98KHZLNAzQQ6AEwCnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=science%20%2B%20physics%20%2B%20%22energy%20is%20expended%22&f=false)

3) It can be seen that for all types of deformation and all metals investigated the percentage of the energy stored is high when the total energy expended during deformation is small, and that it decreases rapidly with increasing work done.

[total energy expended](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1955.0216)

expended means "used up". The words cost and consumed are not used in your context in the form you have provided them. Consumed is used for electricity. Machines consume energy. And cost is about price, literal or not, so, it is irrelevant here.

[[You might want to take care not to expend too much energy in scientific writing. Caveat: joke on the question's wording. ]]

Please note: this answer contains examples. A comment did not provide enough room so I decided to post an answer.

That said, I am no materials scientist (unless you consider being a linguist being a scientist), but I can say this. All other things being equal, for a sentence in the form given by the OP

energy is A, B, or C [past participles of verbs expended, consumed or cost] through process 1, 2, 3 or 4.

It is my opinion that only the verb "expended" works there. Processes expend energy, they don't consume energy and they don't cost energy either.

USAGE, here, therefore is:

- Energy is expended through a process or when a force is exerted.
- A process expends (uses up) energy.

The last example posted by the OP is a comment:
**"for an elastic spring, the energy is expended partly on kinetic energy and partly on potential energy."**

Energy is not expended there. Please note: Energy is stored in the elastic spring (compression) and it can be released when the spring elongates.

Proof of this from a professor at Stanford University

> In physics, elastic energy refers to the energy released when a spring elongates. When a spring is compressed it stores energy that can be used later, at this point the spring contains elastic potential energy. [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=u0gmQ07nyyMC&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=science%20%2B%20physics%20%2B%20%22energy%20is%20expended%22&source=bl&ots=DOZ8GdmK-F&sig=ACfU3U1m2z5PET_HUc5PaDnST7v6TgexDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0xc7VlozgAhXxV98KHZLNAzQQ6AEwCnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=science%20%2B%20physics%20%2B%20%22energy%20is%20expended%22&f=false) Releasing the spring, or elongating it, releases the elastic energy, allowing the spring to move.May 11, 2017
>
> [Elastic spring](http://Elastic%20Energy%20and%20The%20Kangaroo%20JP%20Cannistraro%20May%2011,%202017)

Comment: I know nothing about physics particularly. But I would bet my soul that energy is said to be expended. And I thought I **limited my answer to that and the deformation of metals***. That said, I am not seeing cost energy as you are saying it is used...I did say in my answer: in these sentences. Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: searching for "costs energy" [as noun]  + friction=0; "cost energy" + deformation: returns verbs such as: "Stretching [a process] costs energy, which is stored as elastic energy." [from MIT]; Just as you said. But nothing like: energy costs [some thing]. The OP's question was in the form: energy is A, B, or C through process 1, 2, 3 or 4. So, I repeat, linguistically, one cannot say in a scientific paper: "energy is cost through process 1, 2, 3 or 4" [the verb cost is not used passively]; energy + consume through friction=1 hit; energy is expended through friction: 63 hits in good English.

Comment: And consumed through [a process] is prevalent but not in a materials' sense as given by the OP.

Comment: For someone with such high-level credentials, you certainly missed the point I was trying to make. My answer was really more to give examples from similar contexts, and to say that in the OP's context ("energy is expended/cost/consumed through deformation/vibration/friction") expended is best. Cost and consumed would not work there. You misread what I said, and then provide search terms outside the purview of the OP's actual question. I should have just made a comment and be done with it. And there is no need to shoo a fly with a hammer.

Comment: correx: been done with it.

Answer (score 6):

The word to use depends a lot on the situation:

- In cases where it is not easy to get the energy back into an easy-to-use form but the transformation caused by the energy is desired, it is common to say that energy is ***expended*** (or, less formally, ***spent*** or ***used***) to achieve the desired result.
- In cases where it is not easy to get the energy back and the transformation is not desired, it is common to say energy is ***lost***.

> The work *expended* for plastic deformation cannot be *gained back* completely. Some energy is *lost* in the process. (Slightly paraphrasing from [*Handbook of Physics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=c60mCxGRMR8C&lpg=PA167&ots=HDTzSYfKd0&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q&f=false)).
>
> Energy is *expended* to launch a rocket into orbit. However, more specifically, chemical potential energy is *converted* to kinetic energy and gravitational potential energy when a rocket is launched, although some energy is *lost* to friction between the rocket and the atmosphere.
>
> A can crusher *expends* energy to crush a can, while a car running over a can *loses* energy due to plastic deformation of the can. A perpetual motion machine is impossible because all mechanical systems *lose* some energy to friction.

- In cases where it is easy to get the energy back into its original form (or at least into a highly usable form), it is common to say the energy is ***stored*** or ***converted***. Potential energy is *stored* in a spring, electrical energy is *stored* in a capacitor.
- In chemistry, an endothermic reaction ***absorbs*** or ***requires*** energy. (In an exothermic reaction, energy is *released*  or *liberated*.)
- When concentrated or organized energy is dispersed or made disorganized, the energy is said to be ***dissipated***. Damping a vibration *dissipates* energy. "[Energy *dissipation* rate](https://petrowiki.org/Energy_dissipation_rate) is the parameter to determine the amount of energy *lost* by the viscous forces in the turbulent flow."
- Soundproofing materials ***absorb*** acoustic energy. Molecules *absorb* spectral (light) energy.
- When something hot cools down and in the process heats something else up, energy is ***transferred*** from the hot thing to the cold thing.
- The amount of energy it takes to do something is its energy ***cost*** or the amount of energy ***required***.

  > Foot contact time... is a strong predictor of locomotor energy *costs*, but it does not explain the variance in rate of energy *expenditure* during locomotion.... *Nature, Scientific Reports* [Terrestrial locomotion energy costs vary considerably between species...](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-36565-z)
- In cases where it is hard to get the energy into an easy to use form but you do it anyway, energy is ***harvested***. In some sense, *harvested* is the passive form of *expended*, because the energy is being put to useful work, but the agency is given to some other system, not the system that is the source of the energy. The sun does not *expend* energy to create electricity on Earth, instead, solar arrays *harvest* the sun's energy to create electricity.
- The amount of energy intentionally transferred out of a system (such as a laser or electrical generator) for some other purpose is its energy ***output*** or the amount of energy ***generated***. An electrical generator *generates* energy that is *used* or *expended* by something else to do useful work.

There are lots of other examples, and it is best to look for specific examples as similar to your situation as possible. That said, you can generally fall back on energy being *expended* to do something you want or *lost* to something you would prefer did not happen.

With respect to energy, the word ***consumed*** is rarely used in scientific literature. I could only find it in biology, referring to living things that *consume* energy, meaning either the energy in the food they eat or the energy they expend on biological processes. Energy consumption is more commonly used in non-scientific literature to talk about the amount of energy used by devices (e.g. refrigerators, cars, lights) or groups of people using devices (e.g. United States per capita energy consumption) without respect to what the energy is used for.

Some more papers to look at: [Swimmers](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep05904) spend/expend energy, A [quantum refrigerator](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-08090-0) removes energy, and in the process energy is exchanged, transferred, and redistributed, reaching equilibrium when energy flows are balanced.

Answer (score 3):

Friction **dissipates** energy.

> 1a : to break up and drive off
>     dissipate a crowd
>     1b : to cause to spread thin or scatter and gradually vanish
>    one's sympathy is eventually dissipated — Andrew Feinberg
>   **1c physics : to lose (heat, electricity, etc.) irrecoverably**

[dissipate: Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissipate)

> The problem of vibrations in the blades of conventional engines is addressed by including an outer shroud disposed on the outer radius of each blade. Adjacent shrouds come in contact with each other **to dissipate energy through friction at the interface**, thereby alleviating vibrations. A drawback is that the edges of the shrouds at the point of contact wear out with time and can no longer reduce the vibrations, thus eliminating the mechanism for dissipation of energy.

[Friction damper for gas turbine engine blades](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5522705A/en) (patent)

Comment: i just edited the question. what if the system has no dissipative mechanism, as in elastic vibration or deformation where there's no energy loss but energy transfer, is 'dissipate' still the best choice here?

Comment: No, you can use *expended* there if you like. Although *expended* tends to imply an effort over a decent period of time. You really need to provide sample sentence and context to get a drop-in word.

Comment: let me give an example. for an elastic spring, the energy is expended partly on kinetic energy and partly on potential energy. is the 'expend' here appropriate? if not, what word will b a good sub

Comment: Do you actually address the question?

Comment: @Lambie Well, it did before the Q edit. It was only about friction then.

Comment: @feynman In your new example: "The energy in an elastic spring **comprises** both kinetic energy and potential energy. That is, the energy of a colliding projecting is **converted** into kinetic energy and potential energy in the spring." Please consider adding all your example sentences to the question rather than distributing them across answers. You seen to assume that one single word is appropriate for multiple scenarios, which may not be the case.

Answer (score -2):

Energy can neither be destroyed nor created (conservation of energy) hence cannot be consumed per se - expended is your best choice here; Google NGram finds "cost" the least commonly-used construction of those you suggested in your post:

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expend%20energy%2C%20consume%20energy%2C%20cost%20energy&year_start=1600&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpend%20energy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsume%20energy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccost%20energy%3B%2Cc0)

Albeit true that NGram Viewer is *not* restricted to scientific writings, there have been a number of well received peer reviewed papers demonstrating that in the more recent portions of the Google NGrams English corpus, scientific papers are in fact ***over***-represented in proportion to the rest of the English corpus.

I will add one reference to support this useage:

[Google books - Handbook of Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=c60mCxGRMR8C&lpg=PA167&ots=HDTzSYfKd0&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: 'expend' is not commonly used in science. any other examples of using this word please?

Comment: @feynman expend is commonly used when collocated with energy. My goodness.....I wonder where you got the idea it isn't used in science; it's very used in physics.